# В чем смысл тогда использовать string библиотеку для getline?

Tags: c++

Я вот читаю Дейтела, а точнее о классах. Там написано, что для того чтобы воспользоваться функцией getline(), надо добавить библиотеку <string>. Но, я использовал его в своем коде, не объявляя при этом эту библиотеку и программа сработала, не выдавая ложный ответ и ошибку.
Так вопрос: Тогда зачем добавлять эту библиотеку, если он и без него будет работать?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class GradeBook
{
      public:

                    void Soobshenie(string CourseName)
             {       
                    cout << "My Grade Book for the " << CourseName << endl;
             }
};

int main()
{
    string NameofCourse;
    GradeBook myGradeBook;

    cout << "Please Enter Your Course Name\n";
    getline (cin, NameofCourse);

    myGradeBook.Soobshenie(NameofCourse);

system ("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> для того чтобы воспользоваться функцией getline(), надо добавить библиотеку <string>. Но, я использовал его в своем коде, не объявляя при этом эту библиотеку и программа сработала, не выдавая ложный ответ и ошибку

Проблема в том, что Стандарт не оговаривает внешнюю завязку одних include'ов на другие, потому может получиться, что, например, включив заголовочный файл `list` вы можете получить доступ к `for_each`. Однако никто не гарантирует что это будет работать для стандартной библиотеки, поставляемой с другим компилятором или даже для другой версии этого же компилятора.

> Так вопрос: Тогда зачем добавлять эту библиотеку, если он и без него будет работать?

Затем, чтобы код был переносимым для других компиляторов/платформ, ибо Стандарт оговаривает что включение `string` должно давать доступ к `getline`.

Comment: ясно, значит это важно для переносимости. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Два варианта ответа.

Либо какая то библиотека подключила неявно библиотеку string.

Либо подключили другую библиотеку, в которой есть функция с таким именем.

В старых версиях gcc (<4.2) библиотеки сильно ссылались друг на дружку. Когда эти ссылки поудаляли, многие ругались, что их код перестал компилироваться.

Вывод: раз автор говорит, что нужно добавить, добавляйте. Возможно в будущем это сэкономит кучу времени.

Answer (score 2):

Заголовок string во многих компиляторах включен в  заголовки iostream, fstream  и другие. Поэтому при их включении автоматически оказывается включенным и string. Такая ситуация, например, в gcc или Intel C++ Compiler. Но в других компиляторах, например, в компляторе VS (не помню, как он называется) другая ситуация. Там требуется явное включение этого заголовка в программу. Поэтому для переносимости кода между компиляторами и платформами рекомендуется включать все, что положено.